# Executing keyword based Excel sheet test case as TestNG test case using selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium

We are going to build Keyword based framework; where tests will be mentioned in Excel sheet where every rows will be a step in test case. We can write every component to read/interpret/execute the test case. But we want to execute this test case as a TestNg test case to avail all the benefits like reporting associated with TestNG framework.

Do we have ways in TestNG where we can create TestCase, TestSuite objects in java and submit such a TestSuit to TestNG to run.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG basically has the following

- `XmlClass` - Represents an actual class which contains one or more `@Test` annotated test methods. `@Test` methods are the smallest representation of work. It typically can be visualized as an equivalent to one manual test case (a manual test case is basically a combination of one or more set of steps along with verification points).
- `XmlTest` - Represents the `<test>` tag. The `<test>` tag is the smallest logical unit. It contains one or more test classes.
- `XmlSuite` - Represents the `<suite>` tag. The `<suite>` tag is basically a combination of one or more `<test>`

You should basically create corresponding objects for the above cited ones and then run them via the `TestNG` object (This is called as programatic execution of tests)